# failled to access to localhost using volley library

Tags: android, localhost, android-volley

I want access to my localhost I use xamp and i have changed the default Ip from my localhost and I put my network Ip in my app using volley library. the network address  works if I use by mobile navigator and fail if I use library volley in my app. But if I use another address like [www.googl.com](http://www.googl.com) on my app I will have a response. Anybody can help me because I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Your Android device is its own localhost. Every pc, laptop or Android device is its own localhost. So you probably have several localhosts. Please rephrase your post.

Comment: Can you use dots to mark the end of a sentence. Its all pretty unreadable.

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear .I found the answer here https://android.developreference.com/article/11323473/Volley+library+does+not+connect+to+10.0.2.2 .Thanks to the contributors